# Arguments at instantiation of a namespace

Tags: javascript, constructor, namespaces

I have a namespace generator that looks like this: (As a requirement, it also needs to have prototype objects *extra* and *default*).

```
function generateNamespace(staticMethods, prototypeMethods){

     var namespace = function(){};  //create namespace
      /**add staticMehods and prototypeMethods to namespace*/
     extend(namespace, staticMethods); //extend function from NojeJS
     extend(namespace.prototype, prototypeMethods);

     //create extra and default objects. 
     namespace.prototype.default = namespace.prototype.default || {};
     namespace.prototype.extra = namespace.prototype.extra || {};

     return namespace;
}
```

The idea is to generate a namespace like this:

```
var protObj = {id: function(){
                     console.log("id");                
                   }
              }
var myNameSpace = generateNamespace({}, protObj);
```

When I instantiate:

```
var instanceOfmyNameSpace = new myNameSpace();
```

the result contains the functions `id`, and the objects `default`, and `extra`.

But if I run:

```
var instance2 = new myNameSpace({test: "foo"});
```

Then: `assert.equal(instance2, instanceOfmyNameSpace) \\=true`

so that means(?) that the given object just gets ignored.

What do I have to do to merge that object with the `default` one, for example? The perfect input/output would be:

```
//input
var instance2 = new myNameSpace({test: "foo"});
//output
console.log(instance2.default.test) \\->  "foo"
```

**UPDATE, ANSWER**

All I needed to do was create the `namespace` as a `constructor`, and then add `staticMethods` and `prototypeMethods` to it:

```
  var extend = require('util')._extend;
   function generateNamespace(staticMethods, prototypeMethods){
      var  namespace = function(defaults, extras){
           this.default = extend({}, this.constructor.default, defaults);
           this.extra = extend({}, this.constructor.extra, extras);
      }
      extend(namespace, staticMethods); 
      extend(namespace.prototype, prototypeMethods);

      return namespace;
   }
```

Comment: Just a note: you don't usually instantiate a namespace. Namespaces are typically used to encapsulate instantiatable or other standalone members (values, functions, etc). It looks like what you really want is to create a class, not a namespace.

Comment: It also doesn't look like `prototype` is defined on the line `namespace.prototype.default = prototype.default || {}`

Comment: I already updated that. But that is not the problem. And even if I create a class, instead of a namespace, would that help me merge the method `default` given at instantiation with with the `default` object inside of `prototypes`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show how you are copying `prototypeMethods` or even `staticMethods` to `namespace` which makes answering the question hard. I typically use a copy function to do operations like these. It would work for both the static and prototype methods.

Here is the mixin/copy function:

```
var mixin = function (obj, mixins) {
    var keys = Object.keys(mixins);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        obj[key] = mixins[key];
    }
};
```

And you would use it like:

```
function generateNamespace(staticMethods, prototypeMethods){
     var namespace = function () {};  //create namespace

     // copy staticMethods to namespace
     mixin(namespace, staticMethods);

     // copy prototype members
     mixin(namespace.prototype, prototypeMethods);

     //create extra and default objects. 
     namespace.prototype.default = namespace.prototype.default || {};
     namespace.prototype.extra = namespace.prototype.extra || {};

     return namespace;
}
```

Also note that with the line: `namespace = function(){};  //create namespace` you need to add a `var` as I did when declaring `namespace` otherwise the variable is made global and could exhibit unexpected behaviors.